# Angular $resource does not parse correctly an integer response

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am using the Angular $resource to make requests to my controllers, implemented on a Spring application. 
When the controller returns just an Integer value, $resource parse it bad. 
Inspecting it with Firebug I get something like:

```
Resource { 0="1", 1="9", 2="1", more...}
```

where 191 is just the intger value the server returns.
No trouble with others complex object (parsed in JSON by the server). 
Suggestions?
Thanks
FB

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a little old, but I just ran into a similar problem and someone pointed me in the right direction.

If your server is sending back a JSON encoded resonse, but you only pass it a single value (191 in your case), $resource seems to interpret it as a string, which it is then splitting into an array of individual characters (I'm not 100% on the technical details of why, but that was my experience). So what you need to do is send back your value wrapped inside of a JSON object.

So, instead of doing something like:

```
function callback(req, res) {
    var number = 191;  // this is just for example purposes
    res.json(number);
}
```

You need to do something like:

```
function callback(req, res) {
    var number = 191;  // again, just for an example
    res.json({ value: number });
}
```

Then when your $resource call comes back, just access the `value` property of the response and you should be good to go.

*P.S. The examples here are based on a Node/Express back end, not Spring, but I think this should still apply.*

Comment: This actually solved my issue, I was providing res.json with a string of a JSON object instead of a JSON Object.

Answer (score 0):

Set `isArray: false` in the $resource method definition.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting the [`responseType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#responseType) in the action config, like this:

```
$resource(url, {}, {
    get: {
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'text'
    }
});
```

If that doesn't work you probably need to use `transformResponse` or an $http interceptor to modify the response before the resource gets a hold of it. [See $http docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found this to be an issue with integers, strings, and bools.

If you are using WebAPI, do something like this:

```
public object ControllerMethod(<PARAMS>)
{
    <LOGIC>
    return new { value = <PUT YOUR VALUE HERE> };
}
```

If Node, use CodeLander's answer.

In your Angular code, you'll just have to get the .value of what's returned.